# Need a box and on select and clicking on ">>" goes to next box

Tags: php, jquery

I need a component in which I can select the options and while clicking on select or >> sign it will appear in another box. I don't know what this is called and how to do it. 
Please also view image below:[image: Need such component]

Comment: Please share the code that you've tried so far.

Comment: @Blue Rose WHat you want in next box?

Comment: hello I don't know how to do that, so if I don't know then how can I write code??

Comment: Start by writing the necessary HTML code.

Comment: I want the option choosen in the first box to be displayed in next box.

Comment: You can do this easily by simple JS function and help of jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use multiselect with `jQuery`.  [Good tutorial for this](http://loudev.com/)

Use this HTML code to create your UI:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="path/to/multiselect.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <select multiple="multiple" id="my-select" name="my-select[]">
      <option value='elem_1'>elem 1</option>
      <option value='elem_2'>elem 2</option>
      <option value='elem_3'>elem 3</option>
      <option value='elem_4'>elem 4</option>
      ...
      <option value='elem_100'>elem 100</option>
    </select>
    <script src="path/to/jquery.multi-select.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then use this jQuery :

**.multiSelect(options)**

```
$('#my-select').multiSelect()
```

**.multiSelect('select', String|Array)**

```
$('#your-select').multiSelect('select', String|Array);
```

**.multiSelect('deselect', String|Array)**

```
$('#your-select').multiSelect('deselect', String|Array);
```

**.multiSelect('select_all')**

```
$('#your-select').multiSelect('deselect_all');
```

**.multiSelect('deselect_all')**

```
$('#your-select').multiSelect('select_all');
```

**.multiSelect('refresh')**

```
$('#your-select').multiSelect('refresh');
```

This code will help you, even if the link doesn't work. Happy coding.

Comment: Thank you :) This is what I was searching for

Comment: I need one more level, I also want to display submenu of options. Can I do that??